# KDE menu font too small to be readable

Tags: linux-mint, kde, fonts

On the 3840x2160 resolution of a Linux Mint 20 Cinnamon 16:9 oled screen, the menu fonts of kde related applications (KWrite, ktorrent, digiKam, Gwenview, anki, Dolphin) are too small to be readable. Below a comparison of libreoffice correct sizes and KWrite unreadable fonts' sizes :

[image]

An increase of fonts' size in the system graphical interface has no impact.

The fonts are the following :

```
Default font:  Ubuntu Medium 10
Desktop font: Ubuntu Regular 11
Documents font: Sans Regular 11
Monospace font: Monospace Regular 11
Windows' title font: Ubuntu Medium 11

text scale: 1,2
Optimisation: complete
```

On a brand new Mint the fonts were of a correct - larger - size.

The output of `inxi -Fxz`:

```
System:
  Kernel: 5.4.0-56-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 9.3.0
  Desktop: Cinnamon 4.6.7 Distro: Linux Mint 20 Ulyana
  base: Ubuntu 20.04 focal
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: Dell product: XPS 15 7590 v: N/A serial: <filter>
  Mobo: Dell model: 0VYV0G v: A00 serial: <filter> UEFI: Dell v: 1.4.0
  date: 11/11/2019
Battery:
  ID-1: BAT0 charge: 48.4 Wh condition: 87.4/97.0 Wh (90%)
  model: SMP DELL GPM0365 status: Discharging
CPU:
  Topology: 6-Core model: Intel Core i7-9750H bits: 64 type: MT MCP
  arch: Kaby Lake rev: A L2 cache: 12.0 MiB
  flags: avx avx2 lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx
  bogomips: 62399
  Speed: 800 MHz min/max: 800/4500 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 801 2: 800
  3: 800 4: 800 5: 800 6: 800 7: 800 8: 800 9: 800 10: 800 11: 800 12: 800
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel UHD Graphics 630 vendor: Dell driver: i915 v: kernel
  bus ID: 00:02.0
  Device-2: NVIDIA TU117M [GeForce GTX 1650 Mobile / Max-Q] vendor: Dell
  driver: nvidia v: 450.80.02 bus ID: 01:00.0
  Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.8 driver: modesetting,nvidia
  unloaded: fbdev,nouveau,vesa resolution: 3840x2160~60Hz
  OpenGL: renderer: GeForce GTX 1650/PCIe/SSE2 v: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 450.80.02
  direct render: Yes
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel Cannon Lake PCH cAVS vendor: Dell driver: snd_hda_intel
  v: kernel bus ID: 00:1f.3
  Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.4.0-56-generic
Network:
  Device-1: Intel Wi-Fi 6 AX200 vendor: Bigfoot Networks driver: iwlwifi
  v: kernel port: 3000 bus ID: 3b:00.0
  IF: wlp59s0 state: up mac: <filter>
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 953.87 GiB used: 74.52 GiB (7.8%)
  ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 model: SSDPEMKF010T8 NVMe INTEL 1024GB size: 953.87 GiB
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 937.40 GiB used: 74.52 GiB (7.9%) fs: ext4
  dev: /dev/nvme0n1p2
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 40.0 C mobo: N/A gpu: nvidia temp: 51 C
  Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A
Info:
  Processes: 338 Uptime: 8h 17m Memory: 15.27 GiB used: 4.11 GiB (26.9%)
  Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Compilers: gcc: 9.3.0 Shell: bash v: 5.0.17
  inxi: 3.0.38
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scale factor has to be 1. I guess it's a bug between KDE and Mint.